# Safari animation compatibility issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I created simple animation using html, css and js, it work on chrome, firefox, edge , IE9, but doesn't work on safari.

Also js code was wrapped in:

```
window.onload = function(){ };
```

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gorez16rus/e8ux5u67/)

Comment: Works fine in `Versión 10.0 (12602.1.50.0.10)`

Comment: Are you using Safari on Windows? If so I think it's been deprecated?

Comment: No I am using Safari on Mac, version of Safari is 9.0.3

Comment: Works perfectly fine on `Safari 10.0.3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to avoid using event handler `window.onload`. Use `window.addEventListener('load', callback);` instead. The reason for this is that you might have only one event handler registered on an object. You can attach multiple event listeners though. You problem might be that an event handler is overwritten somewhere else. Try attaching an event listener and give it  a try.

Good luck!